# The Interpreter used by django application

Tags: django, interpreter

I have hosted my django application with apache and mod_python. When i was going through the mod_python documentation, I found that there is a way to know under which interpreter my application is running (By using req.interpreter).

I tried to check that in django, by checking request object. But I couldn't figure out(request.interpreter doesn't exist).

Is there a way to get interpreter name in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from mod_python import apache
apache.log_error("INTERPRETER %s" % apache._interpreter)
```

Then check the Apache error log file.

Comment: Thanks, It worked with a small change. It should be apache._interpreter(_ prefix is missed in your answer).